# How to Predicate through Nested Arrays with Keys

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have an array called `self.eventsArray` which looks like this:

```
[ 
  {
        "artist": [
            {
                "artist_name": "Dillon Francis", 
                "name": "Dillon Francis", 
            }, 
            {
                "artist_name": "Major Lazer", 
                "name": "Major Lazer", 
            }, 
            {
                "artist_name": "Flosstradamus ", 
                "name": "Flosstradamus", 
            }
        ],  
        "name": "Mad Decent Block Party NYC", 
    },
  {
        "artist": [
            {
                "artist_name": "Ryan Raddon", 
                "name": "Kaskade", 
            }
        ], 
        "name": "Kaskade Atmosphere Tour NYC", 
    },
]
```

I have been trying to filter it by using `NSPredicate` two times. When the user searches, it needs to be filtered by either name (in the artist array) or name (in the top-level array).

```
NSPredicate *predicateEventsByName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K contains[c] %@",@"name",searchText];
NSPredicate *predicateEventsByArtistName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K.%K contains[c] %@",@"artist",@"name",searchText];

NSMutableArray *unfilteredEventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
unfilteredEventsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateEventsByName]];
[unfilteredEventsArray addObjectsFromArray:[self.eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateEventsByArtistName]];


 [self.filteredEventsArray addObjectsFromArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:unfilteredEventsArray] allObjects]];
```

Using this code, `self.filteredEventsArray` will be populated with any search term matching the top-level `"name"`. It won't give any search results for the nested artist `"name"`.
I suspect the reason why it won't search through the nested array is because of this line:

```
NSPredicate *predicateEventsByArtistName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K.%K contains[c] %@",@"artist",@"name",searchText];
```

but I can't figure out how to change the `predicateWithFormat:` to make it search through the nested array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"artist" is an array, therefore you have to use "ANY" in the predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@",
              @"artist",@"name",searchText];
```

Note that instead of building the "union" of the search results manually,
you can use a "compound predicate":

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                          @[predicateEventsByName, predicateEventsByArtistName]];
self.filteredEventsArray = [self.eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed. Will the compound predicate show all the results from both subpredicates and exclude the duplicates?