# Objective-C- NSPredicate- Filter NSArray Containing Dictionaries that contain NSArrays of custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, nspredicate

In my app, I'm displaying a contact list in a `UItableView` with sections. My datasource is a `NSMutableArray` holding `NSDictionaries` that hold arrays of two custom object types (see below `debugDescription`).

The first section displays contact groups names (`SNPgroupData.groupName`) and the rest displays contacts sorted by the first letter of their `SNPcontactData.contactName` property. 
This all works well, the problem comes when I want to search for a specific item in the tableView.

Is it possible to use `NSpredicate` (or other methods) to filter any item (groups & contacts) that has a property that contains (`contains[c] %@",searchText?`) the search string?

The following `NSArray` is the datasource for my `UItableView`:

```
  {
        Groups =     (
            "<SNPgroupData: 0x16e5ae80>",
            "<SNPgroupData: 0x16d9ff80>"
        );
    },
    {
        A =     (
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dd5fd0>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d8a840>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dd68b0>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dd7a10>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dcef60>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d9dc90>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dd6950>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16db5070>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d98820>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dac810>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d8e510>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dbf5d0>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dcfbd0>"
        );
    },
    {
        B =     (
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dae7b0>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dd6ef0>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dd9f90>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d8e480>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d9c750>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d9ba20>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16d9ba40>",
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dd6e20>"
        );
    },
    {
        C =     (
            "<SNPContactData: 0x16dcf790>"
        );
    },
```

---

**UPDATE:** following the comments below and information found here:[How to Predicate through Nested Arrays with Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240373/how-to-predicate-through-nested-arrays-with-keys/18240482#18240482) , I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

    NSLog(@"%@",[self.groupedAppContacts debugDescription]);

    self.filteredContacts=self.groupedAppContacts;

     NSPredicate *groupNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.groupName contains[c] %@",@"Groups",searchText];  //this filters out only the group objects but disregards their names

     NSPredicate *contactNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.%K contactName contains[c] %@",searchText]; //this crashes 

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                              @[groupNamePredicate, contactNamePredicate]];
    [self.filteredContacts filterUsingPredicate:predicate];


}
```

I'm able to filter out the group objects from the Array but I get all of them and not only the ones starting with my searchText character.
Tried to get the contact Predicate to work in different ways but since the array name are diffrent for every one of them the predicate either does not do anything or crashes the app (unable to parse)

Answer (score 0):

There is (as far as I know) no direct method to apply a filter to the "inner arrays" of your
data source, and return a new data source array of the same structure.

You have to filter each array of custom objects separately, using predicates like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"groupName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText] // for groups
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText] // for contacts
```

and then build a new data source array.

Comment: Couldn't it be possible to run two sub-predicates and then require in the master predicate that both sub-predicates return more than zero objects? I am kind of dizzy due to a cold, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @LeoNatan: `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns a "subarray" of the original array, but here we need the array with modified elements. - The only alternative that I can think of is to apply `filterUsingPredicate ` to the inner arrays if they are mutable. But this would modify the original data source. - Get well soon!

Comment: Thanks guys. I've posted an edit following your comments. still unable to filter out the objects individually. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can make things a lot easier for yourself by approaching your problem in a slightly different way:

- Use [`UILocalizedIndexedCollation`](http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/) rather than dividing up contact information manually.
- Store group names in a separate array property from contacts. You can do a switch on the table view data source section to pull the correct data.
- If you *really* need to use a predicate to filter out data and can't figure out how to do it with predicate syntax, use [`NSPredicate + predicateWithBlock:`](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/).

Comment: for my next release, I would like to implement your approach, will it work for users who store contact names in multiple languages?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but for what it's worth, I eventually went with the following approach:
-two separate filtering processes
-the group filtering is fairly simple since I have one dictionary holding group objects that I filter by evaluating the groupName property
-for contacts, I have multiple dictionaries (representing contacts with names starting with a specific letter) and I've decided to examine the first letter the user enters, pull the relevant dictionary and then evaluate the contactName. Yes, this approach will only work for contact names that start with a specific search query but it fits my needs.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
    self.showFiltered=NO;
    [self.contactsTable reloadData];

}else{
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.contactGroups debugDescription]);

    NSPredicate *groupNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
                                       ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
                                       {
                                           return [[[evaluatedObject groupName] substringToIndex:searchText.length] isEqualToString:searchText];;
                                       }];

    self.filteredContactGroups = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.contactGroups filteredArrayUsingPredicate:groupNamePredicate]];


    NSLog(@"filtered Names: %@", self.filteredAppContacts);

    NSString *firstLetter = [searchText substringToIndex:1];

    NSMutableArray *filteredContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *letterDictionary in self.groupedAppContacts) {
        if ([letterDictionary objectForKey:[firstLetter uppercaseString]]) {
            filteredContacts = [letterDictionary objectForKey:[firstLetter uppercaseString]];
        }
    }
    if (filteredContacts.count>1) {
        NSPredicate *contactNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
                                             ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
                                             {
                                                 return [[[evaluatedObject contactName] substringToIndex:searchText.length+1] caseInsensitiveCompare:searchText];
                                             }];


        self.filteredAppContacts = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[filteredContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:contactNamePredicate]];


        NSLog(@"filtered Names: %@", filteredContacts);
    }else{
        self.filteredAppContacts = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:filteredContacts];
    }

    self.showFiltered=YES;
    [self.contactsTable reloadData];

}
```

}